# Plot curve fit with errorbars

Tags: matlab

When curve-fitting using the Matlab package cftool, there is an option to generate code corresponding to a fit.  Here is a sample result:

```
%% Fit: 'myfit'.
[xData, yData, weights] = prepareCurveData( x, y, weights);

% Set up fittype and options.
ft = fittype( 'a^x+b', 'independent', 'x', 'dependent', 'y' );
opts = fitoptions( ft );
opts.Display = 'Off';
opts.Lower = [-Inf -Inf];
opts.StartPoint = [0 0];
opts.Upper = [Inf Inf];
opts.Weights = weights;

% Fit model to data.
[fitresult, gof] = fit( xData, yData, ft, opts );

% Plot fit with data.
figure( 'Name', 'myfit' );
h = plot( fitresult, xData, yData );
% Label axes
xlabel( 'x' );
ylabel( 'y' );
grid on
```

I would like to plot the same fit with custom error bars, using a separate vector of errors.  Ordinarily, I would use the function `errorbar()` in place of `plot()`, but it does not accept `fitobject` objects like the `fitresult` in this code.  In fact, the only reason this code works with `plot()` is that there's [an overloaded version of `plot()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/plot.html) in the curve-fitting toolbox, totally separate from the normal `plot()`, that does accept these objects.

**How can I plot cftool fits with errorbars?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot a fit and errorbars on the *data*, not the fit, use:

```
plot(fitresult, xData, yData);
hold on;
errorbar(xData,yData,errors, '.');
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you already have the fit, so you can just interpolate the y-values of the fit using `feval()`. Pair this data with your custom errors and send that to `errorbar()`.

```
yFit = feval(fitresult, xData);
errorbar(xData,yFit,xError,yError);
```

Comment: This puts error bars on the fit, not on the data.  Useful idea nonetheless.

Comment: If you want the error bars on your raw data, then can't you just use errorbar() with your raw data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want errorbars to be incorporated into your fit.

If you want to display both 'a' and 'b' with errorbars representing the CI, you can extract the CI using the [confint](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/confint.html) function:

```
errorbar([fitresult.a; fitresult.b], diff(confint(fitresult))/2,'x')
```

Comment: I'm using custom error bars separate from the fit, so this isn't quite what I want.